# How do we find the general term from an infinite nested radical

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am struggling on how we definite infinite nested radical.

Consider $ {\sqrt  {2+{\sqrt  {2+{\sqrt  {2+{\sqrt  {2+\cdots }}}}}}}}$

From what I have researched, I know we can consider the above expression as the limit of a certain squence. I know how to find this value. However, I would like to find the general term of the corresponding sequence but I do not know where to start. I tried and error but failed.

Is there any formula/theorem that are specialised for finding the general terms of such thing?

Many thanks.

Comment: Hint: let $a_n=2\cos(\theta_n)$. How do $\theta_n$ and $\theta_{n+1}$ compare using the half-angle formula?

Comment: Thanks for clues. Could I ask how you came up with the '2' in $_=2\cos(\theta_{n})$. What if we have something like $\sqrt {1+2{\sqrt {1+3{\sqrt {1+...}}}}} $?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think that the case you ask about in your question is extremely special.  Even in the case $\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\ldots+\sqrt{6}}}}$, I don't think that you can solve for the partial terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you google for the value of trigonometric functions of angles $\theta_n=\frac \pi {2^n}$ (for $n=2,3,4,5$, you will find them in http://mathworld.wolfram.com, you will notice
$$\cos\left(\frac \pi {4}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt 2$$
$$\cos\left(\frac \pi {8}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{ 2+\sqrt 2}$$
$$\cos\left(\frac \pi {16}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{ 2+{\sqrt {2+\sqrt 2}}}$$
$$\cos\left(\frac \pi {32}\right)=\frac 12 \sqrt{ 2+{\sqrt {2+{\sqrt {2+\sqrt 2}}}}}$$

Do you see the pattern ?

Comment: That is very smart! However, how you noticed the linkage of this with my given nested radical? Is it just something that pops up commonly among nested radicals?

Comment: @AnsonNG: the iteration $x\mapsto\sqrt{2+x}$ and the cosine bisection formula are closely related.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Set $x=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2\ldots}}$. Then $x^2 = 2 + x$.

Comment: He says he knows how to find the value, he's really looking for the partial term, like $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}$.